# What is the cardinality of sigma algebra generated by set $X_{i}$ such as

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=[0,1]^{n}$. The question is what's the cardinality of $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $X_{i}:=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n):x_i < \frac{1}{2}\}$, $i=1,2,..,n$?

We are talking about the $\sigma$-algebra defined like this $\sigma(\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\})$ right? So is the answer just $2^{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Intersections of sets of type $X_i$ and their complements give you a partition of $X$ into $2^n$ elements. The $\sigma$-algebra generated is then somewhat bigger.

Given the partition $P=\{\xi_1,...,\xi_{2^n}\}$ of $X$ the generated $\sigma$-algebra consists of all the possible collections $\sigma(P)$ of elements of the partition. To count them note for each $A\in \sigma(P)$ either an element of the partition is in $A$ or it is not. So you should count all such possible choices.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know how to count it :(